# Vb asp .net webform download excel file return the wrong extension and file name

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, iis, webforms

**Hello,**

I have my web application you can download excel file.

- In both local machine and testing server: the file name is returning
  with right extension and right name  but
- in production server it return the name of the page  name

  for i.e  :
- in my local machine and test server   **I get => report.xlsx**  (picture 1)
- production server **I get => FileDownloader.aspx** (the name of the page) (picture 2)

[image: in server test]
[image: in server production]

> I have webappilcation with .Net version 4.7.2

this the code I use to return the file:

```
Sub BuildHtmlResponse(bytes As Byte(), fileName As String, pFileDownloadType As eFileDownloadType, isCached As Boolean)

            Dim encoding As Encoding, contentType As String, charset As String

            Select Case pFileDownloadType
                Case eFileDownloadType.Pdf
                    contentType = "application/pdf"
                    encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
                    charset = "utf-8"
                Case eFileDownloadType.ExcelXls
                    contentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
                    encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
                    charset = "utf-8"
                Case eFileDownloadType.ExcelXlsx
                    contentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
                    encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
                    charset = "utf-8"
                Case eFileDownloadType.Html
                    contentType = "text/html"
                    encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
                    charset = "utf-8"
                Case eFileDownloadType.Txt
                    contentType = "text/plain"
                    encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)
                    charset = "windows-1252"
                Case eFileDownloadType.Zip
                    contentType = "application/zip, application/x-compressed-zip"
                    encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8")
                    charset = "utf-8"
            End Select



            With Response
                .Clear()
                .Buffer = True
                .AddHeader("Expires", "0")
                If isCached Then
                    .AddHeader("Pragma", "cache")
                End If
                .AddHeader("cache-control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0")
                .AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes")
                .AddHeader("content-length", bytes.Length.ToString())
                .AddHeader("content-description", "File Transfer")
                .AddHeader("content-transfer-encoding", "binary")
                .AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & fileName)
                .ContentEncoding = encoding
                .ContentType = contentType
                .Charset = charset
            End With

            Try
                Response.Flush()
                Response.BinaryWrite(bytes)

            Finally
                Response.End()
            End Try
        End Sub
```

**Thank you in advance**

-------- update  I-----------------------------------

```
 Protected Sub Button_Download_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button_Download.Click

   Dim reportBuilder = ReportBuilder.Build()
   Dim reportStream =  reportBuilder.GetStream()

   BuildHtmlResponse( reportStream.ToArray, reportName + ".xlsx", eFileDownloadType.ExcelXls, False)

End sub
```

Comment: Could you show the code where your BuildHtmlResponse method is being called?

Comment: I just called in btn click (see my update upper)

Comment: I have also build a test application on my side, it works well. I suggest you could try to change a browser to download the file to make sure this issue is related with the browser.

Comment: thank you  @Brando Zhang , it's true in firefox browser I don't get the right extension (but in chrome and IE get right extension  but not the right name )   but in my local machine it work nice for all browser but for prod I don t the right name  and in firefox I  don't also get the right extension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the filename in header response was empty (look picture below)

***If no file name set in the header response*:**

- IE, Chrome  => [**page-name**] + [**content-type**("**.xlsx**") ]
- FireFox => [**page-name**] + [**page-extension**("**.aspx**")]

[image: picture http header]

> filename is coming from the global resource (resx).
>     I will set as close because the issue is related more to the global resource

**thank you for all pepole tried  to help me**